# Why simple_html_dom isnt working on html stored in DB?

Tags: php, mysql, simple-html-dom

I have stored few pages html using simple_html_dom in the mysql database like this.

scraper.php

```
<?php
require('simple_html_dom.php');
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("dbname") or die(mysql_error());

$url = 'someurl.html'
$html = file_get_html($url);
$html = mysql_real_escape_string($html);
$query = "INSERT INTO tablename (id, file_get_html) VALUES (NULL, '$html')"; 
mysql_query($query);

?>
```

then if i echo data inserted in db i get the exact scraped page.

but if i try to scrape h1 title of the page using html stored in database then its giving me

**Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in**

for this line

```
$h1 = trim($html->find('h1', 0)->plaintext);
```

complete code here

parse_data.php

```
<?php
    require('simple_html_dom.php');
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("dbname") or die(mysql_error());

    $result = mysql_query("select file_get_html from tablename where id = 1");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $html = $row['file_get_html'];
    }

    $h1 = trim($html->find('h1', 0)->plaintext);
    $title = trim($h1);
    echo $title ;

?>
```

I am doing this so i dont have to scrape the remote page everytime i am doing tests.

how can i get the  content inside h1 tag using simple_html_dom and html data stored in database ?

Comment: Have your database connection work as per given code?

Comment: yes, db is working fine .

Comment: What type of object is `$html` ?

Comment: idk $html is just previously stored data which was scraped using file_get_html, which is simple_html_dom function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is another fucntion called **str_get_html** to load the string html data in variable and parse it using simple_html_dom

```
<?php
    require('simple_html_dom.php');
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("dbname") or die(mysql_error());

    $result = mysql_query("select file_get_html from tablename where id = 1");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $html = str_get_html($row['file_get_html']);
    }

    $h1 = trim($html->find('h1', 0)->plaintext);
    $title = trim($h1);
    echo $title ;

?>
```

notice above, i just replaced

```
file_get_html
```

with

```
str_get_html
```